# Bids on apartments

Tags: economics, real-estate

In some countries, such as the USA, apartments are usually sold through real-estate agents: the buyers send bids to the agent, the agent forwards the bids to the seller, and the seller selects the winning bid.

It is easy to find data on the final price for which a house was sold. Where can you find data on the other bids - the losing bids?

My goal is to build a model for the distribution of bids above the final price.

Probably, real-estate agents have such data, but do they make it public?

EDIT: I will be happy for data from any country.

Comment: Do you specifically want USA? There is a UK site ...

Comment: @MarcusD UK is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For final house prices in the UK, the [HMLR](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/land-registry) (Her Majesties Land Registry) office deals with land ownership, usage and boundary issues along with other miscellaneous land related issues.

For the **data**, you need to go to the [land registry section](https://data.gov.uk/publisher/land-registry) in [data.gov.uk](https://data.gov.uk/data/search) portal.

With regard to bids/offers etc. these are not available afaik and i'm not sure how you would be able to find out, as they will be kept secret by the real estate agents.

A friend in Scotland wrote a script to screen scrape the data from a central repository of proposed house sales and monitored the house price requested over time to see the shifts in the market; but this isn't quite what you are after.